# Using Windows Authentication and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

Do you know whether a SQL Server connection can be authenticated via Windows Authentication but using a not exclusively the Windows Identity/Windows User Name but also a DB login name?

That is, could an SQL Server database have a login that is mapped to a Windows ID so that when you request a database connection you can specify a user name but yet SQL Server knows to look at the Windows authentication ID and validate the login?

Comment: Please consult the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

> could an SQL Server database have a login that is mapped to a Windows ID so that when you request a database connection you can specify a user name but yet SQL Server knows to look at the Windows authentication ID and validate the login?

No.  When you connect with Windows Integrated Authentication you'll be connected as a Windows Login, and for each database you execute statements as the user mapped to that Windows Login (or as dbo if the login is a member of the sysadmin server-level role or the Windows Login is the owner of the database).

You can grant that Windows Login or mapped user the privilege to impersonate some other login or user, but it requires a separate command to perform the impersonation (`execute as user='someuser'`.